# Java - Sending objects with sockets and using a address besides localhost

Tags: java, sockets

So I am starting to learn sockets and I found two problems
1.

```
   InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("75.73.111.104");
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Socket socket = new Socket(address, 57823);
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    out.writeObject("string");
```

So I have that code but whenever I try to connect with it it says"`Connection refused: connect`" But that code was working fine with localhost and it is port forwarded so whats wrong with that.
2.

```
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(57823);
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());                                   
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
if(in.toString() != null)
{
    System.out.println(in.toString());
}
```

When I use that code it does not print the "string" that I typed earlier it gives me the `classname@random` numbers. And it does not see the result as a string but as a object so how do I save objects I have sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using an `ObjectOutputStream` to serialize the object, You'll need to use a complementary `ObjectInputStream` to deserialize the object on the other side.

I think the `ObjectInputStream.readObject()` method should do the trick.

Haven't tested it myself, but give this a try and see what happens:

```
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(57823);
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
System.out.println(in.readObject());
```

Answer (score 1):

Flush the outputstream

```
out.writeObject("string");
out.flush();
```

And at server side read the data from stream

```
 String data = in.readLine();// read data from stream sent by client
System.out.println(data);
```

If you are writing with `ObjectOutputStream` then read with `ObjectInputStream`.

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

String data = in.readUTF();// reading String Object
```

Comment: `out.write()` writes data into stream but do not send it to the client. For sending it to client you need to flush the stream or close the stream.

Comment: `readUTF` is of `ObjectInputStream`. I thought you have made `ObjectInputStream` for reading data as you are writing with `ObjectOutpuStream`

Comment: That was one of my problems

Comment: If you are writing with `ObjectOutputStream` then you should read with `ObjectInputStream`

Answer (score 1):

Your trouble is not with java but with networking. You can't usually access your external IP from the inner network.

Try using an external proxy server or ask someone else outside your network to host the client or the server.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) you can see how to configure a proxy in java. You should use a socks proxy.

[Here](http://www.socks-proxy.net/) you have a list of public socks proxies.